# MySQL Continue Handler Problems inside a Function

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am in process of writing a simple MySQL function that looks up a value in a table and returns it. In case there is not value found it returns null. However, even with a continue handler defined I still end up with a warning "No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed". My code is below, what am I doing wrong? I really want to get rid of this warning :)

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `getCompanySetting`;
DELIMITER |

CREATE FUNCTION `getCompanySetting`(setting_company_id INT, setting_name VARCHAR(255))
    RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
    DECLARE setting_value TEXT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING BEGIN END;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET setting_value = NULL;

    SELECT
        value
    FROM company_settings
    WHERE
        company_id = `setting_company_id`
        AND
        name       = `setting_name`
    INTO setting_value;

    RETURN setting_value;
END|

DELIMITER ;

mysql> SELECT getCompanySetting(24, 'observers_active');
+-------------------------------------------+
| getCompanySetting(24, 'observers_active') |
+-------------------------------------------+
| NULL                                      |
+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                             |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1329 | No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Update: MySQL Version 5.5.25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before  MySQL 5.6.3, if a statement that generates a warning or error causes a condition handler to be invoked, the handler may not clear the diagnostic area. This might lead to the appearance that the handler was not invoked.

I have explained this kind of behavior and the solution in this post:

[Event Scheduler: No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25405/event-scheduler-no-data-zero-rows-fetched-selected-or-processed/29840#29840)

Answer (score 0):

If you ask me there is no better way to fix this kind of issue with handlers or exceptional handling declarative statements.

But you may try to give a constant value that will return even if your answer should be NULL. Let that constant value be a wierdest one that you can expect from the fucntion that could return. Add that constant value to your return function.

**Disclaimer: I haven't tested it, but you may give it a try. Let me know on your results.**

In this case I'm mentioning 'clops' as the constant.

Try below changes to your function only under select clause and see.

```
 SELECT concat('clops',value) FROM company_settings    WHERE
 company_id = `setting_company_id`
 AND
 name       = `setting_name`
 INTO setting_value;
```

> ```
> mysql> SELECT getCompanySetting(24, 'observers_active');
>
> =====>clops
> ```

As only you are aware of the word you may keep that word as a seperator. And at your application end split this word, if you get any other data after seperating 'clops' from the return type then treat it as a real return data. By this way you can ignore/suppress the warning that you get.

Comment: Unfortunately the warning is still there :(

Answer (score 0):

One possible way around it is to generate a query which *always* returns a value:

```
SELECT
    company_settings.value
FROM (SELECT 1 as VAL) AS V
LEFT OUTER JOIN company_settings
ON  company_id = `setting_company_id`
    AND
    name       = `setting_name`
INTO setting_value;
```

You treat the response as if it were part of an outer join and the empty set is now a non-warning `NULL`.